# How to download youtube videos in a universal app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(videoInfoUrl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));

string videoInfo = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd());

NameValueCollection videoParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(videoInfo);
```

My code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(videoInforUrl);
           // HttpWebResponse response = await (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync();

            //Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));

            //string videoInfor=HttpUtility
```

I got issues from `HttpWebResponse response = await (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync();` show `cannot convert httpwebresponse -> getresponseAsynce`.

On universal app not support in `HttpUtility`

Comment: Add a comment here when you get sued or have your app removed from the store. Haven't you read the news for the past few years?

Answer (score 0):

Don't force your typing. Allow it to return what it wants as long as you're able to do what you want with it.

Get rid of the explicit types like this, and you should be fine:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(videoInfoUrl);
var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

The error was occurring because you probably had the `(HttpWebResponse)` in the wrong location. Where you have it would be trying to convert the `Task` that `GetResponseAsync` to the response, which is why you're getting that error.